# Spring-boot: How is "spring-boot-starter-tomcat" included?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

There is a spring-boot web project, and in `pom.xml`, there are following lines:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Seems `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` is part of `<dependencyManagement>` from `spring-boot-starter-web`.

But, a dependency from `<dependencyManagement>` only defines the version, but won't include it by default, right?

If yes, then which part trigger `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` to be actually included in the dependency, since I didn't do that explicitly?

Comment: Have you actually checked the `pom.xml` if you do you will see it is part of the `dependencies` part.

Comment: @M.Deinum Actually, I removed it from `<dependencies>` explicitly, so yes, it's not there.

Comment: As stated have you looked at the [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-web/pom.xml)...

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, I have opened the wrong pom with `ctrl + click` from eclipse, yeah, now I see it's there, thanks.